# Is their way to pull TestCases directly from GIThub repo to Rally Project?

Tags: rally, code-rally

Is there way to pull Test Cases directly from GIThub repo to Rally Project ? instead of creating manually.

we are planning for sync github checked in test cases with rally project test cases apart form direct import option provided by the rally.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone doing this.  It's a cool idea though.  If you get it working it would be awesome if you report back here with your progress.  Even cooler if you can share your implementation on github!

Comment: @Kyle  thanks for reply, ya sure i will get back .